# why my notification sometimes does not appear in status bar?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I try to display a notification using the code like this

```
var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Info")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(notificationMessage.title)
            .setContentText(notificationMessage.body)
            .setContentIntent(setUpPendingIntent(this))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)

 val build = notification.build()
            notificationManager.notify(1, build)
```

and when I create the channel, I use this code

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val infoChannel = NotificationChannel(
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_INFO,
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_INFO,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )


            val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(infoChannel)

  }
```

but sometimes, it does not appear in status bar for Android pie and above ? what should I do ?

Comment: Some more information is needed. But maybe it is because your are using the same `notificationId` every time?

Comment: @Sajjad hmmm notificationID ? do you mean '1' in my code above ? yes the value of 1 is hard coded

Comment: Try to use different IDs each time and see if it changes the condition.